# Клонирование установленной системы (X)Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файловая-система, xubuntu

С целью перехода рабочих мест операторов с Windows на Linux было решено создать образ установленной системы (в нашем случае - XUbuntu, т.к. в XFCE есть кнопка "Пуск") со всем установленным и, главное, настроенным ПО:

1. "Брендированный" интерфейс (заставка, нескучные обои)
2. Удалено не нужное и настроено нужное (вплоть до расширений браузера)

Сейчас клонирование осуществляется с помощью загрузочной флешки Acronis
Если какие "опенсорсные" варианты? 
Clonezilla не подходит по причине нечеловечного интерфейса.

Comment: можно ручками через tar/dd/gz... единственная проблема может возникнуть если где-то uuid'ы прописаны...

Comment: если требуется развернуть образ на хотя бы *сотнях* рабочих мест, то тратить время на «интерфейсы» будет, скорее всего, неразумно. стоит воспользоваться [pxe](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PXE) плюс [tftp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: С каких пор у клонзиллы нечеловеческий интерфейс? И кстати она умеет pxe.