# Можно перенести систему ubuntu с одного компьютера на другой

Tags: ubuntu, резервное-копирование

Есть две машины, одна обычный компьютер на i3, на нём стоит ubuntu 16.04 server
, я веду на нём разработку.
И вторая, 4-процессорный сервер, точную комплектацию не знаю, но в общем это серверная материнка.
Можно ли перенести систему с компьютера на сервер? 
Если бы это была одна и таже конфигурация, можно было бы просто сделать побитовое копирование. а потом осталось бы только настроить сеть.

А вот если это 2 разных компьютера? Возможно ли это в принципе ? Если да то какие возникнут проблемы.
Сразу понятно что будут траблы с драйверами. А с чем еще? И вообще есть ли смысл этим заниматься или проще руками установить систему, и весь софт установить с нуля?

Comment: Начнём с того, что конфигурирование сервера должно осуществляться специальными автоматизированными инструментами вроде Ansible, а не вручную. А вообще систему можно запаковать в tar-архив, распаковать где надо и установить загрузчик для загрузки с распакованной системы (хотя возможно понадобится fstab обновить)

Comment: гы-гы интересная постановка вопроса а слабо на другую аппаратную платформу перенести без перетрансляции ядра?

Comment: набор процессорных инструкций аналогичный? копируйте (проще всё блочное устройство) и запускайте. p.s. того, что пользователи *ms/windows* подразумевают под словом «драйвер», в операционной системе gnu/linux нет по определению. соотвтественно, и «проблем с драйверами» нет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , ну это RISC процессоры оба, поидее набор инструкций одинаковый. .. ????, про драйвера да=) , я новичёк в linux, а как это устроено ? расскажите в крации

Comment: для вашей задачи - изначально есть замечательные средства (docker напрмер). И не надо будет переносить и настраивать ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да, конечно можно, если набор команд «старого» процессора идентичен (или является подмножеством) набору команд «нового» процессора.

простейший способ: переставляете блочное устройство в новый компьютер и загружаетесь с него.

если переставить блочное устройство возможности нет, надо скопировать его содержимое (понятно, что «новое» блочное устройство должно быть не меньше «старого»). для этого оба блочных устройства не должны использоваться (можно загрузиться с любого *live-cd/dvd/usb* с операционной системой *gnu/linux*).

если блочные устройства подключены к одному компьютеру:

```
$ sudo cp /dev/старое /dev/новое
```

если к разным, и есть доступ по протоколу ssh под учётной записью *root*:

```
$ sudo cat /dev/старое | ssh root@новый-компьютер 'cat > /dev/новое'
```

сразу после копирования, при необходимости, можно увеличить размер нужных разделов (или создать новый/-е).

для ускорения передачи по сети поток можно сжать, пропустив его, например, через пару *gzip+gunizp*:

```
$ sudo cat /dev/старое | gzip | ssh root@новый-компьютер 'cat | gunzip > /dev/новое'
```

---

альтернатива вышеизложенному — какие-нибудь специализированные *live-cd* типа *acronis* и т.д. и т.п. но ввиду того, что они делают, в сущности, ровно то, что изложено выше, а из-за «юзер-френдлести» все подробности «скрыты под капотом», я настоятельно рекомендую пользоваться такими «помогателями» только весьма опытным пользователям, которые будут в состоянии «разрулить» возможные проблемы, основываясь на довольно скудной выдаваемой подобными «помогателями» информации.

---

связанные вопросы:

- [Как в Linux клонировать диск в диск другого размера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456192/178576)
- [Как создать резервную копию всего сервера ubuntu 9 с помощью Live CD?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/537954/178576)
- [Клонирование установленной системы (X)Ubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790519/178576)
- [Как перенести всю систему Linux на другой диск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/928906/178576)