# Как перенести всю систему Linux на другой диск?

Tags: linux, hdd, kali-linux

У меня появился новый диск, но я не хочу по новой ставить систему. Есть ли способы полностью перенести всю систему Linux (Kali Linux), а так же все данные на другой диск?

Comment: абсолютно точно так же, как и любую другую систему: быстрее всего — переставить блочное устройство, дольше — скопировать файлы с одного блочного устройства на другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много подходов. Можно воспользоваться утилитой `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

Если переносится не весь диск, а только один раздел, то:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

А можно воспользоваться чем то типа https://clonezilla.org/, которые позволяют загрузиться с usb flash или dvd и копировать диски или разделы.

Дополнительно:

- После копирования стоит обратить внимание на `/etc/fstab`. Если диски монтируются на основе UUID нужно будет прописать новые значения для разделов.
- Если новый диск имеет больший размер, то надо будет создать на нем либо дополнительный раздел, либо увеличить размер текущего раздела. Тут все уже зависит от выбранной файловой системы.

Можно также просто примонтировать оба диска и скопировать данные с одного на другой. В этом случае можно будет избежать последующей корректировки размеров разделов. Но в этом случае, на диск вручную придется устанавливать загрузчик.

Comment: Какой из них менее геморный и более безопасный. На счет `dd`, у меня есть kali linux на флешке, если я с него загружусь и использую `dd` все получится?

Comment: Мне кажется вариант с загрузочным диском наиболее безопасный и менее геморройный. Собественно, для этого его и создавали.

Comment: Тот который clonezilla?

Comment: Да. Есть другие решения, в том числе и коммерческие - типа Acronis. Но Clonezilla тоже хорош.

Comment: Да спасибо, все получилось, но можно еще вопрос, у меня на диске появилось не размечанное пространство(то-есть все разделы скопировались, без изменений) Так вот как расширить корневой раздел? Пробую через gparted, но раздел нельзя увеличть, только уменьшить, но это может быть потому, что я пытаюсь это сделать прям из системы, может надо с Live CD?

Comment: Я писал в ответе, что так оно и получится ) Расширять раздел лучше не в тот момент, когда с него загрузились - либо загрузиться еще разок со старого раздела, либо с LiveCD. Ну и название файловой системы имеет значение. Ext4 ?

Comment: Да, файловая система ext4

Comment: Попробуйте gparted с LiveCD для начала. Если не поможет (хотя все должно получиться): `resize2fs `

Comment: Gparted говорит тоже самое, можете подсказать как пользоваться resize2fs?

Comment: `resize2fs /dev/sda1 100G` - теоритически оно даже на запущенной системе может это делать.

Comment: Я ввел `resize2fs /dev/sdb2 1024G`Он вывел `The containing partition is only 120013824 (4k) blocks. You requested a new size of 268435456` Похоже не не видит не размеченное пространство)

Comment: Попробуйте вот это посмотреть https://superuser.com/questions/1182947/why-is-resize2fs-misreading-the-number-of-blocks-in-my-partition